# How do I pass variables to a sibling controller

Tags: angularjs, controllers, ng-dialog

I have a controller that deals with Purchase orders. It has the purchase order number.

I launch a form in a dialog box which has its own controller.

I need to show the Purchase order number from the PO controller in this dialog box **The third input box on the dialog**.
What's the correct / recommended way to do this?

I'm trying to stick to best practice and the styling guide from John Papa below.

Thanks.

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.6.2/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.6.2/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.6.2/css/ngDialog.min.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="POController as po">
    {{po.purchaseOrderNumber}}
    <button ng-click="po.openDialog()">OPEN DIALOG</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**POLine.html**

```
<div>
  <div>POLINE</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="poline.lineNumber">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="poline.desc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="po.purchaseOrderNumber">
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('app', ['ngDialog'])
    .controller('POController', ['ngDialog', POController])
    .controller('POLineController', [POLineController])


  function POController(ngDialog) {
    po = this;
    po.purchaseOrderNumber = "ORD1234"
    po.openDialog = openDialog;

    function openDialog() {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: 'POLine.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        controller: 'POLineController',
        controllerAs: 'poline'
      });
    }

  }

  function POLineController() {
    poline = this;

    poline.lineNumber = "POLINE12345";
    poline.desc = "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION";

  }


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject into the dialog box controller using the resolve property of ngDialog.open(), like this:

```
ngDialog.open({
  template: 'POLine.html',
  className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
  controller: 'POLineController',
  controllerAs: 'poline',
  resolve: { 
     poNumber: function () { 
        return po.purchaseOrderNumber; 
     }
  }
})
```

Then in POLineController:

```
function POLineController(poNumber) {
  poline = this;

  poline.lineNumber = poNumber;
  poline.desc = "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION";

}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/3x2mQTWUq6StvifxqGTS?p=info)

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately I've not been able to get either of these examples working after trying for a few hours. Are you able to update the plunker? I've been researching it all night and haven't been able to get it working successfully.Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. turns out the issue was a silly one:
.controller('POLineController', [POLineController]);
should have been
.controller('POLineController', POLineController);

your plunker sorted that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way in this scenario would be to pass in the reference to any data using the `data` property. This will allow you to access the data using `ngDialogData` object in the template.

**script.js**

```
  function POController(ngDialog) {
    po = this;
    po.purchaseOrderNumber = "ORD1234"
    po.openDialog = openDialog;

    var data = { purchaseOrderNumber: po.purchaseOrderNumber };

    function openDialog() {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: 'POLine.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        controller: 'POLineController',
        controllerAs: 'poline',
        data: data
      });
    }

  }
```

**POLine.html**

```
<div>
  <div>POLINE</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="poline.lineNumber">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="poline.desc">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="poline.ngDialogData.purchaseOrderNumber">
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#data-string--object--array) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've read through the documentation and have tried lots of examples but for some reason I cant get this working using either of these methods. I can get it working without using these functions by using a service to pass the variables about but I want this app made to best practice and these methods seem more 'legit' than the Shared Service path.

Comment: @McDuff - I created a plunk from your code with my suggested revisions and it works just fine.  Check out the link I added to my answer.  The one addition to your code is that I injected ngDialog into POController.

Comment: @McDuff Can you give up something more than just telling us it doesn't work? Can you provide any errors, logs, or your updated code? Maybe setup a similar example on JSFiddle?

Comment: There were no visible issues 10100111001. no errors in console or anything, the value just wasn't making it to the destination controller. 
Turns out I had made a silly error on my initial controller declaration
.controller('POLineController', [POLineController]);
should have been
.controller('POLineController', POLineController);
Got it now. Thanks for your help.